# How do you disable a WPF ListViewItem in C# code?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm used to the old Winforms way of doing things. Apparently WPF ListViews are full of... XmlElements?  How would I do something like disabling a `ListViewItem`?

```
foreach (XmlElement item in this.lvwSourceFiles.Items)
{
   //disable?

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView` is an `ItemsControl`. `ItemsControl.Items` does not return the child *controls* - it returns the *items* - that is, objects that you have added to the `ListView`, either directly, or via data binding. I guess in this case you have bound your `ListView` to some XML, right?

`ListViewItem` (and other classes like it - e.g. `ListBoxItem` for `ListBox`) is called an "item container". To retrieve an item container for a given item, you should do this:

```
ListView lv;
...
foreach (object item in lv.Items)
{
   ListViewItem lvi = (ListViewItem)lv.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
}
```

Comment: excellent & speedy answer! I didn't know that about WPF ListViews. Yes it is bound to an XML file. 

Your explanation was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `ListViewItem` that represents the data item. You can achieve that through the `ItemContainerGenerator`

```
foreach (object item in this.lvwSourceFiles.Items)
{
    UIElement ui = lvwSourceFiles.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as UIElement;
    if (ui != null)
        ui.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

**You can Perform that In XAML Easily**